# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have added dependencies and also added maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } to my `build.gradle` files. But still getting errors as:

> Failed to resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2
>
> Failed to resolve com.google.firebae:firebase-core:11.4.2

This is the **build.gradle** file in root one

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    maven{ url "https://maven.google.com" }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The below is **build.gradle** file in app one

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
       dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'

    // Displaying images
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any help here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update `compileSdkVersion` to at least 26.  From https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases,

"When you upgrade your app’s Play services dependencies to 11.2.0 or later, your app’s build.gradle must also be updated to specify a compileSdkVersion of at least 26 (Android O)."

Comment: Thank you for help. I did it and updated the compileSdkVersion to 26, and also updated other dependencies. **But the problem still persists**.

Comment: I should also have mentioned that you also need to update your support library versions to at least v26.  Have you done that?